# I have a problem using 'except' code in python

Tags: python

```
try:
    if name > 3:
        print("hello")
        except:
            print("There is something wrong")

  File "<ipython-input-4-5ef2c08f130f>", line 4
    except:
         ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

THIS ERROR IS OCCURING PLS HELP.

Comment: `except` goes at the same indentation level as the `try`.

Comment: @paxdiablo this edit was useless as the question should be removed and as you changed the code (one line) that leads to the SyntaxError.

Comment: @finnmglas, no, I believe that indent level was left in the same place as the original code, feel free to check (I just did). Whether the question is worthy of staying is a matter separate from the correct formatting. I suspect you're right but I'll leave it up to the swarm to decide that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `except` keyword must be at the same indent level as `try`:

```
try:
    if name > 3:
        print("hello")
except:
    print("There is something wrong")
```

Although there's precious little in there that can cause an exception. So, on the off chance you wanted to print either of those strings based on the value of `name`, that would be:

```
if name > 3:
    print("hello")
else:
    print("There is something wrong")
```